# Download a html file in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to use the WebClient class to download a html file from another website and present it as a text stream, But I'm getting a security error, what am I doing wrong, or is this another one of Silverlights security "Features"

[code]

namespace ImageScrape
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient cl = new WebClient();
        cl.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(cl_OpenReadCompleted);
        cl.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.google.co.uk/",UriKind.Absolute));

    }

    void cl_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        testTextBlock.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

[/code]

EDIT

Thanks guys, I was really hoping I wouldn't have to create this as a WCF service as 1) I only know the basics and 2) The idea is that you can use this .xap without having to connect to a central server, mainly because for this I don't have a server that I could host a WCF service on.

Does anyone know a way to get around this, or anywhere that would host a WCF service for free?

Comment: I don't know silverlight so I'm just fathoming a guess that it could possibly be some XSS protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are security issues with going directly to another site from the silverlight client.

The best work around for this would be to move this code into a web service and then serve the content you require to client from there.